# Upgraded Ubuntu to 14.04, can't login to my account & don't know the password of root

Tags: grub2, login, password

I upgraded my ubuntu from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS recently. While installing the downloaded packages, my system hung up and restarted. That is how the problem started.

It's not taking my old password.

I can't even login as a guest user.

Help me.

Comment: 1 observation that I missed out was that when I deliberately enter a wrong password it says 'Invalid password,please try again' and that when I enter the password I think is correct it displays 'Failed to start session'

Comment: Can you go to recovery mode https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode and run these commands to fix the package manage `sudo apt-get install -f` then `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` there is not much to go in your question but if the package manger is the issue, this may work.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from ubuntu cd, mount your root partition, chroot into root partition an change your passwords.
1 boot live cd
2 open terminal
3 sudo -s
4 mount /dev/sda1 /mnt , if sda1 is your root partition.
5 chroot /mnt
6 passwd root
New password
New password
7 passwd youruser
New password
New password
8 exit
9 umount /mnt
10 reboot